# Are Mate Re-spins Allowed?

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I want to make a Mate Re-spin but I don't know if it's legal or allowed. The website says nothing about re-spins, so I would assume that it's OK but I have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I say yes because Ubuntu operates under the GNU General Public License (GPL) and all of the application software installed by default is free software. In addition, Ubuntu installs some hardware drivers that are available only in binary format, but such packages are clearly marked in the restricted component.

Sources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License

Note: I am NOT an attorney.

Comment: I could not find the licensing terms for the Mate desktop itself on their site, but according to Wikipedia it is GNU LGPL and GNU GPL. Go ahead and make derivative works. If you publish it, use the same licensing or a compatible open source license. (I am also *not* an attorney)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using it for personal use it's probably allowed (if you don't upload/share it there's no way for people to find out anyway). If you're planning on going public with it I'd consult a legal expert first, just to be safe.